# Input of a date is not going correctly to the database in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a problem like this. I am making a web API with express4. In their, I have created a function to save data. Here I am providing my controller.

```
const express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

var  Reservation  = require('../models/reservation');

router.post("/create",function (req,res) {
    const newReservation = new Reservation({
        date: req.body.date,
        from: req.body.from,
        to: req.body.to,
        lab: req.body.lab,
        name: req.body.name,
        email: req.body.email,
        role: req.body.role,
        year: req.body.year,
        reason: req.body.reason,
        state: "Not Comfirm"
    });

    Reservation.saveReservation(newReservation, function (err, reservation) {
        if (reservation) {
            res.send(reservation);
        }

        else {
            console.log('Error in User save :' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));
        }
    });

});

router.get('/notComfirmed', function (req, res) {
    Reservation.findNotComfirmed(function (err, reservations) {
        if(err) throw err;

        if (!reservations){
            res.json({state:false,msg:"No reservations found"});
        }

        if(reservations){
            res.json(reservations);
        }

    })
});


module.exports = router;
```

And here providing my model.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const schema = mongoose.Schema;

const reservationSchema = new schema({
    date:{type:Date, required:true},
    from:{type:String},
    to:{type:String, required:true},
    lab:{type:String, required:true},
    name:{type:String, required:true},
    email:{type:String, required:true},
    role:{type:String, required:true},
    year:{type:String},
    reason:{type:String, required:true},
    state:{type:String, required:true},
});

const Reservation = module.exports= mongoose.model("Reservation",reservationSchema );

module.exports.saveReservation = function (newReservation, callback) {
    newReservation.save(callback);
}


module.exports.findBYDateAndTime = function(date, time, lab, callback){
    const query = {date:date,time:time, lab:lab};
    Reservation.findOne(query,callback);
}

module.exports.findNotComfirmed= function (callback) {
    const query = {state: "Not Comfirm"};
    Reservation.find(query, callback);
}
```

When I tried it with the postman. The date is saving with a timezone. as an example, if I send a date as "2018-06-19" it is saved in the database as "2018-06-19 05:30:00.000".I want to remove that timezone. I search for lots of time in the google and the StackOverflow too. Examples that were in there were not enough to full fill my requirement. So can someone help me to solve this problem?

Thank You!.

Comment: If you send the date “2018-06-19”, what would like to see in DB? Something like this “2018-06-19 00:00:00.000”?

Comment: I like to see it just only the data. like "2018-06-19"

Comment: Ok, then it’s a string type in a date format, not a date type. Or use manan solution if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this will help you [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-dateonly). This is an implementation of the DateOnly library that works with Mongoose.

it is a mongoose date only module which store date with out worried about time zone please tell me if you fix your problem